# Android WebView download not working

Tags: android, webview

I have created one web view having page containing html form and on submitting form (with post method) it should download the file.

I have implemented `webview download listener` so i can handle downloads.

```
@Override
public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition,
                            String mimetype, long contentLength) {
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
            Uri.parse(url));
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "DownloadFile.pdf");
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getContext().getSystemService(Activity.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    dm.enqueue(request);
}
```

Now problem is, 
If i use post method in **HTML FORM** in page, download not working(it is working if i use **GET** method)

in chrome mobile app it's works with post method, but it is not working in android web view.

Comment: have you taken permission write_external_storage

Comment: try hardcoding for a known path for testing purpose and see if that writes to appropriate location

Comment: yes i taken permission , it is downloading successfully if i used GET request

Comment: Hi did you found any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `DownloadManager` doesn't support `POST` method. Please find the corresponding issues [3949](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3949) and [1780](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1780).

You will have to use alternative means to download the file in your application.

Comment: Hi did you found any solution?