# Download file using POST method using webview android

Tags: android, webview

I am downloading .pdf file using chrome, firefox browser and It successfully download file. But when same file url are used in web view It won't download file.
I am using Request Method : POST. Is there any way to download this type of file?

I have seen this link: [Android WebView download not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36648268/5370550)

Can Any one solve my issue to use other way of downloading?

Thank you

Comment: I have the same problem, my download it's fired when I do a post with a button. The downloadmanager doesn't fire in that case. ¿Did you found any solution?

Comment: Did any one found solution of this problem

Comment: Hi did you found any solution

Comment: I have not found any solution. In my case I have specific format for downloaded content. so I have manually create PDF file for that content with same structure as downloaded link.

Answer (score -1):

Use  [MultiThreadDownloader](https://github.com/AigeStudio/MultiThreadDownloader) plugin for android , so you can get direct link of files in webview by below codes :

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() { 
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) { 
       // download(Uri.parse(url)); 
    } 
});
```

When you get a direct link from webview , you can pass it to [MultiThreadDownloader](https://github.com/AigeStudio/MultiThreadDownloader) , for download it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I have already use same listener but it never calls. My download url is based on POST method.

Comment: @Nik Please mention if u have found any alternative for using POST method using webview android

Comment: @atishnaik I have not found any alternative solution for that.